# best method to refer .Net functions via php

Tags: c#, php, .net

can any one please advice me, is there any possibilities to access .Net modules using php

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/class.dotnet.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One thing that i can suggest is

```
step 1 : create web service in .net which is client script enable
         or create one aspx page   
setp 2 : call the web service method or web page using jquery ajax or javascript ajax
```

by this way you can achieve things you want

Answer (score 0):

Ditto pranay. .NET makes it extremely easy to create WSDL-based web services that PHP can easily communicate with. In my experience you should shy away from using DLLs if you can - doing so locks you into running your application on IIS, bit of a nasty surprise and rewrite if you ever need to switch your PHP application to a *nix based server setup.

However, depending on your needs you may not want/need to call it using jQuery. PHP has more than adequate SOAP functionality built into the core.